# systemd and StandardInput. taking control of tty

Tags: bash, gdb, systemd, tty

I have a systemd unit script which looks something like this

```
    cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/hello.service
            [Unit]
            Description=Simple Hello World service
            After=syslog.target network.target

            [Service]
            Type=forking
            EnvironmentFile=/root/hello.env
            ExecStart=/bin/gdb /root/hello
            StandardInput=tty-force
            StandardOutput=inherit
            TTYPath=/dev/pts/0
            TTYReset=yes
            TimeoutStartSec=infinty

            [Install]
            WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The whole point is, i want to start the service with gdb on start up.[Since the process involves lot of environmental variables i cannot use the gdb directly on the process.]
systemctl start hello (which is actually working).

But once i exit out of gdb tty is completely messed up.None of the control key work, ^Z, ^C.

This are the observation till now.

- As describer by systemd man pages with "StandardInput=tty-force", will actually force the executing process to take control of tty.

  Before i launch the process
      # tty
      /dev/pts/0

  ```
      # ps -aef | grep bash
      root      2805  2803  0 10:42 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
      root      2860  2805  0 10:45 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto bash

      After i launch
      # tty
      /dev/pts/0

      # ps -aef | grep bash
      root      2805  2803  0 10:42 ?        00:00:00 -bash
      root      2884  2805  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 grep --color=auto bash
  ```

  - Tried reset the terminal, still doesn't work.
  - subsequent systemctl command dsplay the below error

    systemctl stop hello

    Error creating textual authentication agent: Error opening current controlling terminal for the process (`/dev/tty'): No such device or address (polkit-error-quark, 0)

**So the question is is there a way to reset the tty back to bash ?**